# How to verify if the model validatated from the controller

Tags: cakephp

I have a controller where I am adding some registration values to the table,.. but in the controller I would like to know if the page validated or not, my issue right now is that when it goes to the model and validates and there is an error, it will come back to the registration page but with the password filled in with the hashed value so I need to add something there like if(validated) do this.... Here is my code

CONTROLLER

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array("User");
    var $components =array('Session');

    function index()
    {
        $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));
         $this->layout = 'master_layout';
    }

      function add() { 

          if (!empty($this->data)) {
//HERE I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW IF THE VALIDATION FROM MY MODEL RETURNED VALID OR NOT

             $this->data['User']['user_password'] = Security::hash($this->data['User']['user_password']);
             if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your were registered!.');
                               $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
             }
          }

         $this->layout = 'custom_layout';
      }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to this is to set the `value` attribute for your password input to empty. This is the standard way to do this.

But if you want to know what the errors are and whether the model validated or not, you can also look at the `$this->ModelName->validates()` method of the model.

You can also use this method to get the errors in the model - `$this->ModelName->invalidFields()`

Cookbook link - http://book.cakephp.org/view/1182/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller

This is for CakePHP 1.3

Comment: Okay I can try the easy solution, how would i do this, this is how my password input looks like echo $this->Form->input('user_password', array('type' => 'password', 'label'=>'Password'))

Comment: Just set it to  `$this->Form->input('user_password', array('type' => 'password', 'label'=>'Password', 'value' => ''))` . That way the user will always have to fill in the password again.

Comment: John I  hope you dont mind me asking, but i am new to cakephp, and is been kind of difficult for me as I am converting an old php site to use cake. I have the the registration already saving the data to the db with the password hashed and everything using cake.. now I have a login at the top of the page in a div username and password and a button, when the login is clicked it used to call a jquery ajax function and if good remove the username and password and show a welcome message.. and this div is visible through out the website.. How can I do this with cake? (In theory)?

Comment: I can post a new question but would you look for that question and give me an idea please ?

Comment: You'd do this the same way you'd do it with PHP. The only thing different would be that you'd have an element in the layout file which would contain either the welcome message or the login inputs